# How to take http header response values in a variable?

Tags: php, http, webserver

I have the following response being sent from a server. How do i extract the part of the string www-authenticate into variable called $realm, $nonce, $opaque ?

The following output is being generated by a curl request and i'm printing the response headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2011 05:49:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="users@mris.com", nonce="3133323436313933383137343820335916269c13227f30b07bd83a1c7e0d", opaque="6e6f742075736564"
RETS-Version: RETS/1.5
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the headers into a general array:

```
$headers = explode("\n", $headers);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $header, 2);
    $headers[$key] = $value;
}
```

Then, parse the `WWW-Authenticate` header with something like this:

```
$params = array();
preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]+)"/', $headers['WWW-Authenticate'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $params[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}
```

Comment: This short code has problems with multi-line header values. Just noting, RFC is here: [rfc2616 4.2 Message Headers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.2)

Answer (score 0):

Using the function get_headers http://es2.php.net/get_headers you can get an array with the values of the header.

Comment: this will get the headers for a given url, not for the currently requested script

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = getallheaders();
preg_match_all('/\"([^"])*\"/', $headers['WWW-Authenticate'], $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This gets the headers with getallheaders(), picks your www-auth, and then filters every value between quotes into the $matches array by a regular expression. Access your values via $matches[0] etc.